# itextpdf-7: htmltopdf: No worker found for tag wbr

Tags: java, itext, itext7, html-to-pdf

In some generated HTML, we insert a `<wbr/>` tag to help with line breaks in a table.
However I get this error message:

```
[error] c.i.h.a.i.DefaultHtmlProcessor - No worker found for tag wbr
```

when converting this HTML to PDF with itext7-core-7.1.11 and html2pdf-3.0.0.

```
<td>
  <p><a href="#Corrections">TEST.<wbr/>Corrections</a></p>
</td>
```

The PDF still comes out fine and the text wraps at the desired places, however I don't understand why there is an error message. Any ideas?

Comment: The error message is there because `<wbr/>` tag is not respected and will be ignored

Comment: The <wbr/> tag does what I intended it to do, which is to cause the text to wrap at that point, if needed. So even if it is ignored, it has an effect, which is useful. The error message is unnecessary.